# Получить список почтовых индексов внутри произвольной области

Tags: яндекс-карты

Подскажите, можно-ли получить список почтовых индексов России внутри произвольной области?

Если отталкиваться от координат почтовых отделений, то на ум приходит решение, когда я занесу на карту все почтовые отделения России, потом выделю область, и получу список только тех отделений, которые находятся внутри области. Но это полумера. Не факт, что в нарисованной произвольной области не будет домов, относящихся к соседнему почтовому отделению, которое не попало в область.

Answer (score 0):

[Держите](https://vinfo.russianpost.ru/database/ops.html) сразу для всех областей.
Если нужно искать по точке и радиусу, то можно использовать [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) и [YandexMapAPI](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geoquery.html). Функцию для вычисления расстояния между двумя координатами можно взять [здесь](https://github.com/cmoncrief/geodist).

Comment: Я имел в виду именно произвольную область, а не субъект РФ. То есть я буду выделять на карте полигон и мне нужно понять дома с какими почтовыми индексами в нее входят.

Comment: что-то мне кажется, если речь идет о яндекс картах, то произвольная область это геометрическая область заданная координатами точек, а не перечень территорий РФ